# How to get data from the query set returned from elasticsearch django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am trying to get data from elastic search in my application but its returning a query set which triggers an error in my serializers `"Expected a list of items but got type \"Search\"."`. And when I print results returned from elastic search i get `<django_elasticsearch_dsl.search.Search object at 0x1101f2b00>`. I haven't used elastic search before and its giving hell...

document.py

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index, fields
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer

from .models import Unit, Rental

units = Index('units')


html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer="standard",
    filter=["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball"],
    char_filter=["html_strip"]
)


@units.doc_type
class UnitDocument(DocType):
    rental = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'property_type': fields.TextField(),
        'city': fields.TextField(),
    })

    class Meta:
        model = Unit

        fields = [
            'bedroom',
            'bathroom',
            'price',
        ]
        related_models = [Rental]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Not mandatory but to improve performance we can select related in one sql request"""
        return super(UnitDocument, self).get_queryset().select_related(
        'rental'
        )

    def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
        """If related_models is set, define how to retrieve the unit instance(s) from the related model.
    The related_models option should be used with caution because it can lead in the index
    to the updating of a lot of items.
    """
        if isinstance(related_instance, Rental):
            return related_instance.car_set.all()
```

In my views.py i have tried to capture the anticipated data.

views.py

```
class SearchView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        query_price = request.query_params.get('budget')
        query_bedroom = request.query_params.get('bed')
        query_bathroom = request.query_params.get('bathroom')
        query_city = request.query_params.get('city')
        query_type = request.query_params.get('type')

        query_obj = {
            'price': query_price,
            'city': query_city,
            'bathroom': query_bathroom,
            'bedroom': query_bedroom,
            'property_type': query_type
        }

        if query_obj:
            search_results = UnitDocument.search().query("match", price=query_price)
            serializers = UnitSerializer(data=search_results, many=True)
            if serializers.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            all_units = Unit.objects.all()
            serializers = UnitSerializer(data=all_units)
            if serializers.is_valid():
                return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

setting.py

```
# Django Elasticsearch integration
'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
# Django REST framework Elasticsearch integration (this package)
'django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf',
```

Comment: I think you need an additional step where you convert the ES results into a queryset.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Read the [django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf docs](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/0.17.2/quick_start.html), especially the [ViewSet definition part](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/0.17.2/quick_start.html#id5).

Answer (score 1):

`search_results.to_queryset()` should work fine, search_result is an iterable object that returns dicts with fields of your model, it's not a queryset, you can also try `list(search_result)` but I'm not sure about it

Answer (score 0):

Docs : https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html?highlight=.scan()#pagination

You are doing a scan/scroll

```
   search_result = s.params(
            size=app_settings.RESULT_SIZE_LIMIT, scroll='30m').scan()  
   print("RESULTJSON", result_set)
   for hit in result_set:
      print("EACH HIT DATA", hit)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).